# How do a form a selector using JQuery 1.8.3 that will select the checkbox in the code below?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8

```
<table id="area-work-time" class="table" data-user-message="work time">
<tbody>
  <tr class="work-time-block">
    <td class="days">
      <label class="checbox_label">            
      <span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0px -68px;"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-content-key="Check Monday" data-original-value="False">
      <span class="work-time-text">Monday</span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have the following code that works in Chrome and Firefox, but that solution fails in IE8 using the following:

```
$.each($('.work-time-block'), function () {
    alert("inside work-time-block");
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        alert("inside change event");
    });
});
```

*this is the entire code block*

This suggested alternate syntax(es) `$('input[type="checkbox"]' ...` and the like don't work either, I see the `inside work-time-block` 7 times, one for each `<tr>` that has a `work-time-block` class on it; I never see the `inside change event` alert box, it pops up every time on Chrome and Firefox.

I am not getting any errors other than IE 8 complains about a script running slow every once in a while.

I didn't write this, I inherited it and I know this isn't the correct way to do it but I have tried for over an hour to figure out the correct syntax that will apply this to a `checkbox` in IE 8 with no success, so I appeal to the stackoverflow collective for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried $('input[type="checkbox"]' ... ?

Comment: Do you get an error or anything like that?  Can you set up an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]', this).on('change', function() { ... } );` depending on what `this` is, and that selector should'nt fail in IE8, and I'm pretty sure there problem with IE8 lies elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @jtheman before your comment gets too many more upvotes, I'll ask if you ever have other elements of [type="checkbox"]? Stick with `$('[type="checkbox"]')` or better yet `$(':checkbox')`. Either way, this is avoiding the important question of the context of this line of code. `this` could be anything, maybe it's important, maybe it's a mistake.

Comment: @Sinetheta I added context of `this` either way I don't really care if I have to use an absolute path type reference, the HTML never changes. I just can't get any checkboxes to select and bind under IE 8.

Comment: Might be a dead-end but what if you add `value="1"` to your input tag?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson JS has [function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), we still can't see what `this` is based on what you've posted, we'd need to see what it's "inside" of. However I'm guessing that it's just a mistake, remove it. The problem is not likely in what you've posted, as you can see eskimo's demo below which works in IE. You'll have to start trying to isolate your issue in a demo.

Comment: @Sinetheta Correct. Removing `this` or `$(this)` makes it work in IE8 for me.

Comment: @jtheman the input tag is being generated by .Net

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Great to hear. Sounds like scrappedcolahad the right answer first.

Answer (score 3):

Tested in IE10 running in IE8 browser mode and IE8 document mode:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33uEP/1/

Comment: this might work in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work outside there in IE8 for me.

Comment: Is there much other js on the page where you are having troubles?

Comment: unfortunately yes, crap loads :-(

Comment: I can't remember if IE8 even has any sort of console, but are there any errors on the page?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){window.alert("checked");});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the table data is added by JS then you might want to add an on() handler like:

```
$('#area-work-time').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
    alert("inside change event");
});
```

This makes the event trigger for dynamically created elements.